# Hosting WCF Service on a local machine - DNS work?

Tags: wcf, hosting, dns

I've a WCF service running just on my laptop. The laptop is connected to the web, IP is static.

What's involved in getting that service consumable by a web user (say I'm in Cyprus and my clients are other in the US), can I restrict users by their IP address?

Please not, I'm aware of WCF support for P2P, but that's not what I'm looking for. The service will be migrated to a proper hosting environment after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd let IIS do the heavy work and restrict IPs.

[Restrict IP addresses in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730889%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Just host the WCF inside a web project and use a dynamic DNS service to pass through to your laptop.

HTH

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for that. I've never done that before - could you elaborate a bit on 'use a dynamic DNS service to pass through to your laptop' - how will my server & client WCF binding look like?

Comment: Have a look at http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-pro-free-trial/ ... your bindings should be exactly as before, only thing that changes is the address which will point at your dyn.com address (if your home IP changes you update it with dyn.com) ... Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, any chance to get that done w/out a proxy or with a free service? The solution The service will be hosted for a couple weeks before we will migrate to a proper Sql server hosting.